# Java Serializing with base 64

Tags: java, serialization, encoding, base64

I am trying to send objects to different parts of the environment using base64 encoding, but I get an "Illegal base64 character b7" error.

The encoding code:

```
public static String serialize(Serializable object) throws IOException {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(SIZE);
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)) {
        outputStream.writeObject(object);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
    } 
}
```

The decoding code:

```
public static Serializable deserialize(String base64String) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String);
    try (ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded))) {
        return (Serializable) inputStream.readObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it was in the code that decoded the object - it did not just receive encoded objects, but also regular objects x.x
After putting a check on that, my code worked.